# What is the meaning of performing logical operations on two numbers?

Tags: digital-logic, assembly

If we are to consider two Boolean values, the logical operations on them make perfect sense. But what would it mean to perform AND/OR/XOR operation on two binary numbers?

I am learning Assembly level programming (in ARM7) and I'd to write a simple code that performs logical operations like AND,OR,XOR on two Hex Values.

EDIT: My question is not about the procedure of performing such operations on numbers. I'm concerned about the logical implication of such operations.
I came across a block of code that swaps the value of two registers without involving the third register or memory. The algorithm was to perform XOR operation on the numbers. 
A(XOR)B = A'B + AB' ,
What actually is the meaning of A'? If A were a Boolean Value 0 or 1, A' would have been 1 or 0 respectively. I don't understand how I can extend the same logic for two numbers.

Comment: Most computers internally represent "numbers" as a series of bits.

Comment: I'll continue what @PlasmaHH said, to preform an OR operation on two numbers, you just preform the operation (OR) each pair of bits.

Comment: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~airturk/CSE30/topic06.pdf

Comment: When you write A XOR B = A'B + AB' you are letting the ' character represent the NOT of the bit values. So instead you could have wtitten (NOT A AND B) OR (A AND NOT B). If A=0 then A'=1.

Answer (score 3):

When speaking of logical operations on two numbers, two different kinds of operations might be the case: 
1) The most common one - bitwise operation between two numbers, which, as you hopefully know, represented by bits (zeros and ones). Given two numbers, represented with 8bits each, for example, the bitwise logical operator will perform the logical operation between the two *corresponding* bits of the operands, putting the resulting bit into the corresponding place in the result. (say AND operation of third bits will yield result in the third bit). 
2) Less common are the *reduction* operators, that will perform logical operations on the bits of the *same* operand, reducing the result to one bit. I.e. performing the reduction AND on a number will perform AND between all of it's bits and return the only one resulting bit.

Upd:
The answer for your updated question:

For swapping two boolean variables A and B we might perform the following operation:

```
A <- A xor B 
B <- A xor B
A <- A xor B
```

Here, if we denote by `A'` and `B'` the original values of `A` an `B` (please note, i am not using the `'` as NOT, it just an indication to differ two variables),
the lines will become:

```
A = A' xor B'
B = (A' xor B') xor B' = A'
A = (A' xor B') xor B =  (A' xor B') xor A' = B'
```

And thus the values are swapped.
If we extend the same to A and B containing more than one bit, the same operation will be performed on each their bit (columnwise in your terms), effectively swapping the values of the whole numbers.

Answer (score 2):

When performing a NOT on a single boolean value, then you're correct in pointing out that it's an inversion of the value.

```
A  = 1
A' = 0
```

When A is represented by more than one bit, then all the bits in A will all be NOT'd independently.

```
A  = 00110101
A' = 11001010
```

The representation of binary in hex allows us to shorten how these numbers are represented. So in the case of A above:

```
A  =    0011 0101
A  = 0x 3    5
A' =    1100 1010
A' = 0x C    A
```

So when A = 0x35, A' = 0xCA.

The same applies to AND, OR, and the other bitwise operators.

```
A = 1
B = 0

A AND B = 0
A OR  B = 1

A = 0110 = 0x6 
B = 1101 = 0xD

A AND B = 0100 = 0x8
A OR B  = 1111 = 0xF
```

Answer (score 0):

For sake of simplicity let us assume that the binary numbers are byte values (8-bits).

To perform an AND/OR/XOR between two if these byte numbers means to apply each bit of the eight individually. Thus if we were to do C = A AND B it would have c.7 = a.7 AND b.7. Likewise all the other bits down to c.0 = a.0 AND b.0.

Performing bit group operations like this can be extremely useful in computer software algorithms. In some cases it allows parallel logical operations to be performed on many bits at a time without having to devolve the along string of bits down to doing one at a time. In other cases the numbers being acted upon may being used in a more complex calculation and specific bit values may need to be manipulated. One good example of that is in the computation of a CRC error checking code.

When you said in your question that you wanted to perform logical operations on two HEX values it does point to a common confusion made by beginning programmers. There are distinct differences in what "HEX" numbers can mean in different contexts. One context is at the basic binary level where hexadecimal notation is used as a means to compact way to express binary values. In this case by the time a program is reduced to its machine language equivalent to feed into the computer the numbers are in binary format. Another context is that the program in operation may be directly operating on values that are stored as HEX numbers such that some text is being processed where the data contains stored characters of 0-9A-F.

Comment: I understand that to perform any logical operation on two numbers, we consider each column independently of the other. But my question is about the logical meaning of such operation. 

Aren't logical operations meant for Boolean values and not actually numbers?

Comment: @AdityaPatil Sometimes the logical operation on numbers makes a perfect sense (checksum calculations, bit masking for accessing only parts of the numbers, encryption and so on) If you haven't encountered it yet, you will if continue to deal with digital stuff.

Comment: @AdityaPatil - There exist computers that support the bit-wise logical operations on all bits in say bytes or words at a time. But then also have single bit logical operations as well. One popular architecture that supports this is the 8051 family of MCUs.

Comment: Could you guys please check the edited question and explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Performing logical operations on any number follows the same process as performing a logical operation on two individual bits. For example: to perform an AND operation on `0Ah` (`00001010b`) and `F2h` (`11110010b`) you would AND the individual bits places resulting in a final answer of `02h` (`00000010b`).